# Have the table of contents before the abstract

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, abstract

I am writing an article, and would like the TOC to appear before the abstract but after the title, and the page counter to start from 1 from the abstract. This is how I have structured my report:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
...
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
....
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. The title page has no page number, TOC has number 1, then the abstract has no number and the first page of the actual report has number 1.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Apart from the fragment above which is not really useful yet: titlepages don't have a page number, abstract pages usually are unnumbered and do page number resets (differing from class to class) etc. In addition, you only stated that the page numbering should start with `1` from the abstract page on, but not for the title page. So what is the real issue here?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) ! Here you can find more information to create a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). The compilable code starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

The TOC page is usually numbered, if you want this page to be unnumbered you need to add `\thispagestyle{empty}`. The abstract pages are usually unnumbered but if you want them numbered you should put `\thispagestyle{plain}`. Finally the first page of the reports begins with 1 because the abstract environment resets the page counter, to solve this you can put `\setcounter{page}{2}` after the abstract or, if you want a unusually large abstract, you can save the page of the last page of the abstract and then change the page of the first page of the actual report to the value you saved before plus 1. The following code should solve your problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document} 

\maketitle 
\tableofcontents \thispagestyle{empty} 

\begin{abstract} \thispagestyle{plain} 
    Abstract 
    \newpage
    Abstract 
    \newcounter{savepage} \setcounter{savepage}{\thepage}
\end{abstract}

\setcounter{page}{\thesavepage} \stepcounter{page}

Text 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the table of contents may well be more than one page long, so `\thispagestyle{empty}` is not enough.

Comment: Thanks for this remark, one possible solution could be to redefine the page counter style to “nothing” and then make it normal again. The following code should overcome this issue: 

`\renewcommand\thepage{}` after documentclass and `\newpage \renewcommand\thepage{\arabic{page}}` after `\tableofcontents` instead of `\thispagestyle{empty}`

Comment: Wait a minute, why not simply `\pagestyle{empty}` right before `\tableofcontents` and `\cleardoublepage \pagestyle{...}` (replace dots with whatever page style you want) just after it?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti out of memory, standard `\tableofcontents` in standard classes resets the pagestyle, so it is not enough to set it to empty before. So if the table of contents extends across three pages, you will have problem at least with intermediate one.

Comment: @jfbu: You are right, I was forgetting that, in the `report` and `book` classes (and in other classes as well) `\tableofcontents` issues `\chapter*`, which in turn sets `\thispagestyle{plain}` (it is this what you mean, isn’t it?)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti yes, that's it. Now I remember that one has to be extremely tenacious to get rid of it: `\usepackage{etoc}`, `\renewcommand\etocaftertitlehook{\thispagestyle{empty}\pagestyle{empty}}`, `\renewcommand\etocaftercontentshook{\cleardoublepage}` for the `book` class.

Comment: @jfbu: Yes, and also that `tocloft` package has provisions for that.